# Почему не отправляется email?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Не отправляется email, вот код такой (Codeigniter)

```
$this->email->from($email,$username);
$this->email->to("elivin87@gmail.com");
$this->email->subject("Feedback ");
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();
```

Ну, я какие конфигурации должен сделать? Когда пишу в форме свой email (hotmail), все показывает правильно, и на email (тот емаил, который указал в форме) приходит сообщение, что не отправлено. Где ошибка? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите сообщение об ошибке, которое возвращается на ваш емайл для начала. Что там прописано, что не найден адресат или что почта адресата переполнена или что-то еще. И от этого пляшите уже. Если бы скрипт не отправлял, то вы в скрипте ошибку и получали бы, а так получается отправка срабатывает, но до конечного не доходит, значит, ищите в адресе ошибку или в чем-то подобном.

Answer (score 2):

1. Используй отдельно функцию:

   ```
   function _email($from, $to, $subject, $message)
   {
       //$site_name = config_item('site_name');
       $site_name = 'hashcode.ru';
       $this->load->library('email');
       $this->email->clear();
       $this->email->initialize(array('useragent' => $site_name, 'mailtype' => 'html'));
       $this->email->from($from, $site_name)->to($to)->subject($subject)->message($message);
       if ($this->email->send()) return TRUE;
       else return FALSE;
   }
   ```
2. Там, где нужно отправить, в функции пишешь так:

   ```
   $this->_email('email_from@mail.com', 'email_to@mail.com', 'Тема', 'Сообщение');
   ```